# Prometheus error - Error on ingesting samples

Tags: prometheus

I am getting following error in Prometheus on monitoring my Node JS based web application.

> level=warn ts=2019-08-02T18:23:48.658364708Z caller=scrape.go:932
>   component="scrape manager" scrape_pool=batch_web
>   target=https://example.com:443/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples
>   that are too old or are too far into the future" num_dropped=6

Any pointers on why this could be happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: Prometheus doesn't accept samples with historical timestamps. If you need storing samples with out of order timestamps, then take a look at other Prometheus-compatible systems with backfilling support such as [VictoriaMetrics](https://victoriametrics.github.io/#backfilling).

Answer (score 3):

- Enable debugging mode in Prometheus by passing `--log.level=debug` as an argument to prometheus
- Check the log. In my case the metric that was dropped, was returned:

  ```
  msg="Out of order sample" series="some-metric{a="b",c="d"}
  ```
- Check the prometheus configuration and rule files that could return a duplicated `some-metric`. In my case a duplicated rule was causing the issue as the same metric was scraped from the federated prometheus and calculated again by my prometheus. Removing the duplicated rule solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Working with prometheus on virtual machines in VMware, vagrant and Paralles virtual environments, all running Ubuntu 18.04, I had the same promblem with this message in syslog

```
msg="Error on ingesting out-of-order samples"
and veraious num_dropped= values
```

The thing that worked was to issue ALL of these command, on each image, then reboot the image.  Without the reboot the num_dropped began to be lower but the error persisted until the reboot

```
/usr/bin/timedatectl set-ntp false
systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd
systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
systemctl mask systemd-timesyncd
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue ( on CentOS7 OS). In my case the /etc/ntp.conf was pointing to a non-existing server, resulting in out-of-sync server time.

In the prometheus server logs I was getting below error message-

```
target=http://localhost:9090/metrics msg="Error on ingesting samples that are too old or are too far into the future" num_dropped=380
```

Solution:

You can use the below public servers in your /etc/ntp.conf file:

```
server 0.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst
```

Follow then below steps:

1. Restart ntp service

   systemctl ntpd restart
2. Stop Prometheus service

   systemctl stop prometheus

Go to the Prometheus data directory and remove everything inside it:

```
ls -lrt
drwxr-xr-x 2 prometheus prometheus     6 Oct 20  2021 chunks_head
-rw-r--r-- 1 prometheus prometheus     0 Oct 19 21:18 lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 prometheus prometheus 20001 Oct 19 21:20 queries.active
drwxr-xr-x 2 prometheus prometheus    66 Oct 19 21:18 wal
```

3. Start Prometheus service